# Simple HTML DOM get value "data-url" from <div> tag

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get the value from "data-url" from tags like this:

```
<div class="event event-list " data-id="24692" data-url="https://www.example.com/events/20-01-2017-event-x/">
```

this code is not working:

```
$urlVariable =  ('https://www.example.com/');

$html           = file_get_html($urlVariable);

foreach($html->find('[data-url]') as $detailLinks)                                              
print $detailLinks . '<br>';
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That looks like a `<div>` tag, not `<meta>`.

Comment: thank you very much!!! this works. can you please post your solution as an answer, so I can mark it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find div with data-url attribute

```
foreach($html->find('div[data-url]') as $detailLinks) 
   echo $detailLinks->{'data-url'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achive the desired result using domxpath too in the following way:

```
<?php

$html = '<div class="event event-list " data-id="24692" data-url="https://www.example.com/events/20-01-2017-event-x/">';
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

print $xpath->query('//div[starts-with(@class,"event")]')->item(0)->getAttribute('data-url');
```

or

```
print $xpath->query('//div[contains(@class,"event-list")]')->item(0)->getAttribute('data-url');
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. splash58's solution is working for me. greets

Comment: that's great, then it is for another approach :)